# Customized keyboard

Tags: android

I am very new to developping Android application and I am facing a
difficulty.

What I want to do is to use a specific keyboard when I click on an
`EditText`. So far, I have found the `Keyboard` and `KeyboardView`
classes but I haven't succeeded to do what I want yet.

Here is the description of where I am :

- I have described my keyboard in a XML file,
- I create a "KeyboardView" object,
- I initialize it with `clavier=new KeyboardView(activité,
  (AttributeSet)findViewById(R.xml.clavier_numerique));`
- but I don't know how to replace the standard keyboard with this
  customized keyboard.

Am I doing something wrong? What else should I do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like this:

```
    //retrieve the keyboard view from xml
    kbdV= (KeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.kbd);

    //set the keyboard layout to the layout you defined in res/xml/keyboard_layout.xml
    kbdV.setKeyboard(new Keyboard(this,R.xml.keyboard_layout)); //defines the keyboard layout

    //add a keyboard action listener
    kbdV.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener(){
        public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
            handlePress(primaryCode, keyCodes); // callback to handle keypresses
        }
        public void onPress(int primaryCode) {}
        public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {}
        public void onText(CharSequence text) {}
        public void swipeDown() {}
        public void swipeLeft() {}
        public void swipeRight() {}
        public void swipeUp() {}
    });
```

with a layout xml file similar to this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!-- your widgets here -->

<KeyboardView android:id="@+id/kbd" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you should decide what you want from keyboard:

if you just want to change to numbers you can do that by the first answer from Macarse
if you want a complete customized keyboard you should use `Keyboard` and `KeyboardView` classes by a second project

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an `inputType` in the xml:

```
<EditText android:inputType="textUri"/>
```

or from the code doing:

```
EditText input;
input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

You can read the available `inputType`s [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#Searchable%5FinputType).

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize it with clavier=new KeyboardView(activity,
(AttributeSet)findViewById(R.xml.clavier_numerique),EditText edit);
You can transfer the EditText object in. And hide the standard keyboard，show the customized KeyboardView like this.

```
public void showKeyboard() {  
 if (edit != null) {
         InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edit.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    keyboardView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    keyboardView.setEnabled(true);
}
```